# Uncaught Error: No module: ngRoute

Tags: angularjs

i am using ngRoute module but its showing me error so is there extra file need to add for using this module i search but i did'nt found like other modules resourse,cookies we need seperate files for is it for ngroute also if yes so where can i found this

**Error:-**

```
Uncaught Error: No module: ngRoute 
var app = angular.module('inventoryApp', ['ngCookies','ngResource', 'ngRoute']);
```

**controller.js**

```
app.controller('storesController', function ($rootScope, $scope, $location, $cookies, $routeParams) {

});
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You do need a separate file. Please see:

http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute

> First include angular-route.js in your HTML:

```
<script src='angular.js'>
<script src='angular-route.js'>
```

Answer (score 6):

As of AngularJS 1.2.0, ngRoute is separated in its own module.

Download: http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.1/

Changelog: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md