# Add a Controller in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-controller

I am trying to create a controller for a view in angularjs. I just created the file detailCtrl.js in the controller folder with this content

```
angular.module('frontendApp').controller('detailCtrl', ['$scope', '$routeParams',
    function($scope, $routeParams) {
        $scope.name = $routeParams.name
        $window.alert('Works');
}]);
```

And I detail.html

```
 <div ng-controller="detailCtrl"></div>
```

But I get this error

> Unknown provider: $routeParamsProvider <- $routeParams <- detailCtrl

Something is missing ?

Comment: Missing ngRoute module for $routeParams service? See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20008428/uncaught-error-no-module-ngroute

Answer (score 0):

routeParams is include in NgRoute module u need to load it in your application for use it.

```
angular.module('frontendApp').controller('detailCtrl', ['ngRoute','$scope', '$routeParams',
    function($scope, $routeParams) {
        $scope.name = $routeParams.name
        $window.alert('Works');
}]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You also need to include reference to your script in your html file.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="path/to/detailCtrl.js"></script>
```